# magento connection not fully secure

Tags: ssl

I am having an problem securing my site.I went to System - configuration - web and i changed edited the secure configuration[image: secure]

It seemed as though it worked. the only problem is, everywhere on my site i have a secure connection in the backend and frontend execpt for the home page.It says your connection is not fully secure. https://truckpartsactions.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, browsers will render the entire SSL session as insecure if you have one single non-secure call.

FYI, I ran this through an SSL site test, and everything works except for one call:

Insecure URL: http://111.93.221.219/ECO/mag/humvee/skin/frontend/humvee/default/images/gears.svg

The call was found in this file: https://truckpartsactions.com/skin/frontend/humvee/default/css/camera.css

My guess is that this was done during testing or development, as it was in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you hard code any links in any template or CMS Page? In a template drop the http and just put // before our urls. In a CMS page use 
`<a href="{{store url='home'}}"></a>` for your anchors. A great tool to find the offender is whynopadlock.com. It will tell you specifically whats going on.

Comment: i checked the padlock and i was able ti find the files and delete them